# Dynamic link returning empty JSON string from Firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication, dynamic-linking

I'm setting up my Android app to support email authentication and as part of the task I need to create a dynamic link, which I did in the Firebase console. However, when I tested the link (https://chiaramail.page.link/.well-known/assetlinks.json, I just got back empty data ("[]"). Is there something else that needs to happen?

Comment: I got the same empty data... But I have successfully integrated dynamic links. However in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zra2DCd0DnY) he has array with data. I think it has something to do with AppLinks.

Comment: @SajithK I got past this problem some time ago, but am still stuck on creating a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. Actually it is because, you need to provide SHA256 instead of SAH1 to implement dynamic link to your project. I tried to add it with my existing project through project settings. But it didn't work for me.

Then I created a new project and in the sdk configuration I skipped SHA1 input and after completing sdk setup, I went to the project setting and added SHA256. then I tried link `<your dynamic link>/.well-known/assetlinks.json` .It worked.

Thanks Mate.

Comment: is there any way to add it with existing project through project settings because i already have Firebase account i need to use that only.

Comment: I added it as the answer recommends and it took several hours for the assetlinks.json to get updated for me.

Comment: For me, I added SHA256 and then create a dynamic link URL prefix, the old one whose were empty got filled in some way, just some minutes (5, 10 ) after, after I created a new prefix.

Answer (score 4):

For me, no need to create a new project. Just go to Project Setting, add SHA-256, and wait about 15-20 minute to it can up-to-date on `assetlinks.json` site.

- Another faster option without waiting:

1. Add SHA256 on Project Settings
2. Click on `Add URL prefix` from menu dropdown on Dynamic Links page
3. Setup new link

Comment: for me it took around 30 min to update

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a new project for fixing this issue.

if the /.well-known/assetlinks.json return [], the empty array you need to add SHA256 Key to your firebase project.
Follow [this](https://youtu.be/zra2DCd0DnY?t=329) video for more info

solution:

1. Delete the existing deeplink URL prefix
2. Add SHA256
3. Create a new deeplink

finally check the new deeplink  <NEW_LINK>/.well-known/assetlinks.json
It will give something like this

```
[{"relation":["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],"target":{"namespace":"android_app","package_name":"com.test.app","sha256_cert_fingerprints":["sha"]}}]
```

that means it works properly.

Comment: how to add sha256?

Comment: do you know what would be the expected behaviour if our web app doesn't have native apps? I saw these requests being made by the bot. should we just ignore or put an empty json? I couldnt find information about this case

Comment: Delete the existing deeplink URL prefix - this is not an option for me, I've added the SHA256 so I will wait and see if it updated itself after a few hours

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set up the dynamic link, no need to create a new dynamic link to fix this. Just add the `SHA256` in the project settings.

**Note**: If your releases are signed by Google Play, then go to the play console, open the app. On the left side menu, go to Setup -> App integrity -> App signing. Under **App signing key certificate**, copy **SHA-256 certificate fingerprint** and paste it in the firebase console -> project settings for Android.

For more details or any other issue, go to the link `https://<your dynamic link>?d=1`. (*?d=1 is important, it is to debug the flow of your dynamic link*)
If there is an issue, it will show you a warning like `The dynamic link has a warning`.

Expand the warning and it shall show you what is wrong and how to fix it.